# Выставить скролл страницы ниже элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, menu

Есть горизонтальное меню, которое всегда зафиксировано вверху страницы. Скрипт позволяет добавлять и удалять класс active для пункта меню при скролле странички, если вы попадаете на раздел сайта, совпадающий с пунктом меню. Чтобы эта функция верно срабатывала я отнял высоту меню так:

```
target.position().top - 70
```

Также при нажатии на пункт меню нас скроллит к блоку с соответствующим айди этого пункта. Но т.к меню фиксировано сверху, то оно перекрывает верхушку блока и нужно скроллить ниже на 70, для того чтобы учитывать высоту меню и блок с информацией был виден полностью. Не получается выставить эти 70 на скролл.

```
var menu_selector = ".top-menu"; 

function onScroll(){
var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
$(menu_selector + " a").each(function(){
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);
    if (target.position().top - 70 <= scroll_top && target.position().top + target.outerHeight() > scroll_top) {
        $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$("a[href^=#]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(document).off("scroll");
    $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: target.position().top 
    }, 1500, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });

});

});
```

Comment: `scrollTop: target.position().top + 70` не?

Comment: В том то и дело, что "не". Этот вариант работает неправильно. Страница сначала скролится до верхушки элемента, а потом в противоположную сторону на 70 пикселей возвращается, куда и надо. Но необходимо чтобы она скроллилась не в два шага, а одним разовым скроллом до "объект + 70"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hwybsjj5/ можно тут опробывать